# Using Intel AMT (Management Engine) in "standalone" mode without corporate infrastructure?

Tags: linux, remote-access, amt

I'm using a relatively recent Dell laptop and for testing purposes, I've enabled the Intel AMT, aka Management Engine. I don't have any large-scale corporate infrastructure to back me up, but I still would like to use one feature: namely, to have the ME "phone home" with its current IP address every time it's connected to a network.

AFAICT this is possible when using the "official" backend server; is there also a way to access that feature somehow using just a plain Linux box reachable from the Internet?

Comment: Could you not just set your public IP as the "provivsioning server address", and then monitor the port the ME usually contacts for profile updates?

Comment: That sounds like a decent idea, thanks. Do you know which port that is?

Comment: Port 9971, by default, iirc

Answer (score 0):

You can configure AMT locally when the system is booting.  The "phone home" feature requires a bit more to make it work.  You may want to take a look at using it with [meshcentral.com](http://meshcentral.com).  You can get the most from AMT without having to run any software on your own using it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I've given it a try. However, mesh creation fails with 404 every time, so it looks somewhat broken. Is the technology behind that available as open source somewhere?